# Null propagation operator

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

I've looked around a bit but haven't been able to find an answer to how the new C# 6.0 compiler breaks down the new null propagation command for something such as the following:

```
BaseType myObj = new DerivedType();
string myString = (myObj as DerivedType)?.DerivedSpecificProperty;
```

What I want to know is how exactly it handles this.

Does it cache the `as` cast into a new `DerivedType` variable (i.e., this is just syntactical sugar for an `as` cast followed by an null comparison).

Or if it actually `as` cast it, check for null, then if not null, recast and keep going.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it cache the `as` cast into a new `DerivedType` variable (i.e., this is just syntactic sugar for an `as` cast followed by an null comparison).

Yes.

Your code will be compiled to something like this:

```
BaseType myObj = new DerivedType();
DerivedType temp = myObj as DerivedType;
string myString = temp != null ? temp.DerivedSpecificProperty : null;
```

You can see that with [this TryRoslyn example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayAQjVQAVBLlQx0CAPIEAVjAC8MCKgDuMACKoATmB6pBKtZJyzZKW9A0I4yT7CMxTR19GksbOwcnVAkAfgA6K1t7QTg1UjAAMzIABWs+NWtkBFd2AF9sCuxKGjoFEGVVdWwWKpracOSoppgALhh6xrUWmTZOEnIPSFgkyNT0rNz8wuKcMqAAAA==) (though, as hvd commented, by looking at the IL you can see there isn't actually a `DerivedType` variable. The reference is simply stored on the stack).

Comment: Well, no. If you turn off the C# decompilation mode and just check what IL gets generated, you'll see that it doesn't use a variable, it just uses `dup` to duplicate the value on the stack.

Comment: @hvd That's because the only built in reference types in IL are object and string.

Comment: @phoog I have absolutely no idea what you mean by that comment.

Comment: @hvd in IL there is no way to declare a variable of DerivedType or BaseType. Given variables of these types in C#, their IL representation will be `object`.  That's why the cast is a `dup`.  In IL, the reference was never a `BaseType` reference to begin with.

Comment: @hvd I don't think the point is whether the instance is stored *in a variable* or *on the stack* but whether there's an `as` and a null check or is there a recast.

Comment: @phoog There absolutely is such a way, and if you look at the link in this answer, you see that there is *already* a declaration of a variable of type `BaseType`. Not only that, but IL keeps track of which object types are on the stack even without explicit declarations.

Comment: @i3arnon That's fair enough. I thought it would be worth addressing that it doesn't work exactly like the OP suggested, but it is indeed pretty close.

Comment: @hvd I agree. I added a note.

Comment: @hvd never mind.  I was a bit confused.  But so are you: the dup does not represent the cast.  It results from the need to have two instances of the derived reference on the stack. The first one is there to compare with null; the comparison pops two values off the stack, so you need the second instance there to call the property getter. The cast is effected by `isinst`, which pops an object of the top of the stack and then pushes either the object or null back on the stack, depending on whether the argument is assignable to the given type. (And references on the stack have only one type: `O`.)

Comment: @hvd perhaps we are interpreting the question differently.  You seem to think it's asking about "a new variable" in IL, and I think it can't be asking about that, since IL doesn't have local variables; it just has an execution stack and a bunch of arguments.  So the answer to that question is trivially "no."  i3arnon has answered the question in terms of intermediate rewritten C#, which seems a much more reasonable context in which to answer, where the answer is "yes."

Comment: @phoog You're the one who claimed the "cast is a `dup`", whereas I stated it was to duplicate the value (the result of `isinst`) right from the start, and now you're turning it around to claim I'm the one who thought `dup` was for the cast?

Comment: @hvd my confusion results from your comment, which started by simply saying "no" without making it clear what you were saying "no" to.

Comment: @phoog As for "since IL doesn't have local variables", I already pointed you to the `.locals` section... And what I said "no" to? "it doesn't use a variable", from the same comment. I was saying "no" to the claim that it used a variable.

Comment: @phoog No, they're not. How could they be, if the method doesn't take any arguments? They're local variables. The best reference for CIL for me is MSDN, and `.locals` is what gets created by [`ILGenerator.DeclareLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.declarelocal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where you see MSDN refer to local variables.

Comment: @hvd sorry, I didn't realize how sleep deprived I am.  I should stop. But I do have one question: after the `dup` you have two (logical) storage locations (on the stack) referring to the same DerivedType instance (or to null, if the passed BaseType reference is to something other than a DerivedType instance).  Do those two storage locations not represent the use of an additional variable?

Comment: @phoog It's a storage location, sure, but I personally wouldn't call it a variable, since variable already has another meaning within CIL. Also, unlike with variables, the same location on the stack may later be occupied by a different type. But if you do want to call it a variable, that's okay, I guess, I can see now where you're coming from.