# Setting a Value to a field inside an object "Only" if the Value is not null in C#

Tags: c#, object, null

I am new to C#. I can use your help with the below.
I have the following code.

```
    private void foo(TropicalRequest tropicalRequest)
    {
    var buildRequest = new RestRequest()
     {
      BaseUrl = tropicalRequest.baseUrl,
      StatusCode = tropicalRequest.statusCode,
      InitialDate = tropicalRequest.createdDate.Value
     };
    //Code call to save into DB
    }
```

The "tropicalRequest.createdDate.Value" field does not contain value for every scenario, when it is null my code breaks. I have written the below code but I want to optimize it, your help is much appreciated.

```
    private void foo(TropicalRequest tropicalRequest)
    {
    var buildRequest = new RestRequest()
     {
      BaseUrl = tropicalRequest.baseUrl,
      StatusCode = tropicalRequest.statusCode
     };

    if(tropicalRequest.createdDate.HasValue)
      buildRequest.InitialDate = tropicalRequest.CreatedDate.Value;
    //Code call to save into DB
    }
```

Basically, I want to set the value to the field inside the object only if the value is not null.

Edit #1: InitialDate and CreatedDate are both of the DataType DateTimeOffset.

Edit #2: InitialDate is not nullable and CreatedDate is nullable DateTimeOffset.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? it will set value for `InitialDate` if `createdDate.HasValue` right?

Comment: nothing wrong, is there a better way or shorter way of writing the if statement within the object creation?

Comment: Is both your properties nullable DateTimeOffset's or is the InitialDate non-null DateTimeOffset and the CreatedDate of the TropicalRequest is nullable?

Comment: only CreatedDate of the TropicalRequest is nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will already be optimized by the compiler. If you just want to format the code differently you can use this syntax. So the CreatedDate will be used if there is a value and otherwise the value provided on the other side of the ?? syntax, in this case default(DateTimeOffset) which will be the same as not assigning. So one could argue your current syntax is actually "better"  than this.

```
private void foo(TropicalRequest tropicalRequest)
{
    var buildRequest = new RestRequest()
    {
        BaseUrl = tropicalRequest.baseUrl,
        StatusCode = tropicalRequest.statusCode,
        InitialDate = tropicalRequest.CreatedDate ?? default(DateTimeOffset);
    };
}
```

As your InitialDate is non null DateTimeOffset it will be always initialized to Default value of the DateTimeOffset even if you do not assign it.

Comment: this approach worked. I was trying the same with tropicalRequest.CreatedDate.Value ?? default(DateTimeOffset); Which is why it did not work. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use null propogation operator:

```
var buildRequest = new RestRequest()
 {
  BaseUrl = tropicalRequest.baseUrl,
  StatusCode = tropicalRequest.statusCode,
  InitialDate = tropicalRequest.createdDate ?? default(DateTimeOffset)
 };
```

Comment: Are you sure the ?.Value syntax? There is no Value for DateTime.

Comment: Yep. If Value is null in first case InitialDate becomes null, in second case - default(DateTime). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601091/null-propagation-operator) some info about null propagation operator.

Comment: had tried this, dint work because the field is not nullable. when I use the default(DatetimeOffset) I get the error saying "?? operand cannot be applied to operands of Datetimeoffset."

Comment: But there is no Value property on the DateTime. You use the ?. notation to access the properties of the type wrapped in the nullable object. like date?.Year.

Comment: It is a DateTimeOffset datatype. I have updated the same in the question.

Answer (score 0):

An important note, the Default value for the DateTime object is its `MinValue` which means if you have not assign anything means its value will be `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. Consider `tropicalRequest.CreatedDate` is `null` in the second example then `buildRequest.InitialDate` will be the minimum value.

> If you want it to be `null` means it should be of `Nullable` type. you
>   can use the following syntax for defining them.
>
> ```
> DateTime? InitialDate;
> ```

If you declared like this in the class, then you need not to check with `HasValue` property. you can directly assign like this `InitialDate = tropicalRequest.createdDate`

As the other answer stated, you can try [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn986595.aspx) operator If you are using `c# 6.0`. or else Make use of conditional operator :

```
var buildRequest = new RestRequest()
 {
  BaseUrl = tropicalRequest.baseUrl,
  StatusCode = tropicalRequest.statusCode,
  InitialDate = tropicalRequest.createdDate.HasValue ? tropicalRequest.CreatedDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue;
 };
```

Comment: this approach will set a min value, my requirement is to leave the field alone if the value is null.

Comment: @ndavid9: `DateTime.MinValue` is the default value for the DateTime object, if you want it to be null means you have to make it as Nullable DateTime object.

Comment: Yes I understand but in my scenario the InitialDate is not nullable and the CreatedDate is nullable. Also it is of the type DateTimeOffset and not dateTime "DateTimeOffset? CreatedDate { get; set; }"

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` can be Nullable.